# Why can't i do foreach on a json-array-object?

Tags: javascript

I have an javascript object that get's output like this

```
console.log(data.feed.entry);
```

chrome output:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

I thought that [] indicates that it is an array

I try to loop through them like this:

```
var entries = data.feed.entry;
entries.each(function(entry){
   //console.log(entry);
});
```

and get the error "TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'each'"

Here is my object:

```
[
    {
        "id": {
            "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq_23rNPzvODdFlBOFRYWlQwUFBtcXlGamhQeU9Canc/od6/public/values/R1C1"
        },
        "updated": {
            "$t": "2014-02-03T14:47:31.115Z"
        },
        "category": [
            {
                "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
                "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"
            }
        ],
        "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "A1"
        },
        "content": {
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "First"
        },
        "link": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq_23rNPzvODdFlBOFRYWlQwUFBtcXlGamhQeU9Canc/od6/public/values/R1C1"
            }
        ],
        "gs$cell": {
            "row": "1",
            "col": "1",
            "$t": "First"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq_23rNPzvODdFlBOFRYWlQwUFBtcXlGamhQeU9Canc/od6/public/values/R1C2"
        },
        "updated": {
            "$t": "2014-02-03T14:47:31.115Z"
        },
        "category": [
            {
                "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
                "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"
            }
        ],
        "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "B1"
        },
        "content": {
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "asdf"
        },
        "link": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq_23rNPzvODdFlBOFRYWlQwUFBtcXlGamhQeU9Canc/od6/public/values/R1C2"
            }
        ],
        "gs$cell": {
            "row": "1",
            "col": "2",
            "$t": "asdf"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq_23rNPzvODdFlBOFRYWlQwUFBtcXlGamhQeU9Canc/od6/public/values/R2C1"
        },
        "updated": {
            "$t": "2014-02-03T14:47:31.115Z"
        },
        "category": [
            {
                "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
                "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"
            }
        ],
        "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "A2"
        },
        "content": {
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "second"
        },
        "link": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq_23rNPzvODdFlBOFRYWlQwUFBtcXlGamhQeU9Canc/od6/public/values/R2C1"
            }
        ],
        "gs$cell": {
            "row": "2",
            "col": "1",
            "$t": "second"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": {
            "$t": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq_23rNPzvODdFlBOFRYWlQwUFBtcXlGamhQeU9Canc/od6/public/values/R2C2"
        },
        "updated": {
            "$t": "2014-02-03T14:47:31.115Z"
        },
        "category": [
            {
                "scheme": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
                "term": "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell"
            }
        ],
        "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "B2"
        },
        "content": {
            "type": "text",
            "$t": "tada"
        },
        "link": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "type": "application/atom+xml",
                "href": "http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq_23rNPzvODdFlBOFRYWlQwUFBtcXlGamhQeU9Canc/od6/public/values/R2C2"
            }
        ],
        "gs$cell": {
            "row": "2",
            "col": "2",
            "$t": "tada"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Because it's `.forEach()`, not `.each()`.

Comment: Also, it's not a JSON object, JSON is a data serialization format.

Comment: I still sometimes feel, that a programmer can get hung with small problems. `Why always down vote and discourage?` Rather than that, educate user's to check the documentation and read about it or provide valid examples in a comment and close the question if it is small error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`forEach` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var entries = data.feed.entry;
entries.forEach(function(entry){
   console.log(entry);
});
```

Or a regular `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0, n = entries.length; i < n; i++) {
  console.log(entries[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forEach(), or map() options.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array